# How to Get SHA-1 key in React Native cli?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

In React Native when I'm trying to get Google GPS API key in Google console, I have seen package name and SHA-1 key where to I get SHA-1 key in React Native

How to get SHA-1 key in React Native cli? (not in Expo).

Comment: Go to android->app folder and use command -> 
keytool -exportcert -keystore debug.keystore -list -v

Answer (score 74, accepted):

1. **Windows**:
   – Open a terminal window

   – Change the directory to the JDK bin directory. The path of the JDK depends upon the operating system you are using

   `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin`

   – Now we have to run the following command using the keytool.exe file in JDK/bin

   `keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

   [image]
2. **Ubuntu/Mac**

   – Open a terminal window

   – Now run the following command

   `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

   [image]

For more details click [Here](https://aboutreact.com/getting-sha1-fingerprint-for-google-api-console/)

3. From **React-native Project**:
   – Run this command in React-Native App directory

   `cd android && ./gradlew signingReport`

   – copy the SHA1 from the debug key (This generates two variant keys. You can copy the 'SHA1' that belongs to the debugAndroidTest variant key option.)

Comment: this command is very useful "cd android && ./gradlew signingReport" to get report. Thanks.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\programming\zoomino 6\imaps-native\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\aseme\.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\6ozn04tb0t0k7dwz97qf9fvs6).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

Answer (score 15):

There is **debug.keystore** available by default in android => app folder so we can use it to generate SHA1 key.

The command is as follows

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore ./android/app/debug.keystore -list -v
```

It will ask for password so just press **Enter**.

Comment: `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.`

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understand you, it's about Android.

You need input certificate fingerprint, what you use for sign *.apk file.

For generate SHA-1 fingerprint, open a terminal window and enter the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore PATH_TO_YOUR_KEYSTORE.keystore -alias YOUR_ALIAS_NAME -storepass YOUR_STORE_PASS -keypass YOUR_KEY_PASS
```

This should look something like this:

```
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
```

You can find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup)

If you don't have a certificate yet, I recommend you create it.

How to create a certificate you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).

Comment: yes,i know this method in android but when it comes to  react-native while generate signed apk , it does not ask alias in react native instead of this,it ask password and...first name...so why i ask here , what is alias name in react native how i get this.

Comment: Perhaps proposes to create a new certificate?

Comment: Do you have a certificate for this project?

Comment: Yes,i have certificate.

Answer (score 8):

if your are Using react native
and using
`keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/App/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`
there are Chances getting ERROR

***to Avoid ERROR in WINDOWS***

1)Run your Command Prompt As Administrator

2. Navigate to your react-native project's root folder

3)`cd android`

4)type in `./gradlew signingReport`

this will generate All kinds of SHA-1 And SHA-256 and many more details

Comment: I get an error saying this: `Error: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'`

Comment: you need to install react-native/cli

Answer (score 6):

**Get SHA1 Key**

Simple run below command :

```js
keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/App/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: this command is creating same SHA1 fingerprint for all projects. i even create new project and it gives the same fingerprint for all projects

Answer (score 6):

In your react-native root dir paste line below:

```
cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though running keytool on jdk/bin and `./gradlew signingReport` command gives SHA-1 & SHA-256 keys I had troubles when using those keys on firebase / gcp to register my app. For some reason running keytool command on project root folder output gives you a SHA-1 key which can be use to register the app in gcp. In windows, there are the steps you should follow

1. Make sure keytool is the enviroment variable path
2. Open the cmd in your root project folder (eg: C:/myreactnativeproject/)
3. run `keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/app/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

And there is your SHA-1

Answer (score 2):

For me the following command worked, as can be seen below.

```
keytool -keystore android/app/debug.keystore -list -v
```

[image: result of the keytool command]

Answer (score 1):

my solution: keytool -J-Duser.language=en -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 1):

first move to android folder cd android
and than simply run .\gradlew signingReport command
this help me on windows operating system

Answer (score 1):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore you_key_name.keystore -alias your_alias_name
```

Answer (score 1):

** RN / Gradle 2023**

Not sure if this is different for RN 0.7.26 and Gradle @8.0.1 but I had to use my "my-upload-key.keystore" file NOT the "debug.keystore" to get the SHA1.

In the terminal navigate to your main project folder and use this command.

*keytool -list -v -keystore android/app/my-upload-key.keystore*

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First Go To Your Project Directory And Just Simple Run This Command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/App/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

And You Can Get [image]

Answer (score 0):

For React native run this command after opening the android folder

\android> ./gradlew signingreport

after running copy and paste SHA1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).